# Mystery surrounding Ichabod's mother

Tags: plot-explanation, sleepy-hollow

Ichabod's mother is an "innocent child of Nature". What does this allude to?

Also, is it implied that she was insane and this was misinterpreted by his father that she was a witch?

Answer (score 1):

Like the witch in the woods (Lady Van Tassel's sister) she seemed to be a "good witch", which may have appeared to Ichabod's reverend father as a pagan Devil-worshipper.

I saw no evidence of mental illness in the movie, however, simply an ideological clash (why they got married in the first place eludes me...)